# Sending personal notifications from GitLab to Slack

Tags: gitlab, notifications, slack

I'd like to receive all my **personal** GitLab notification that are normally sent as emails to my own private Slack channel.

I'm quite familiar with Slack incoming webhooks, and I also know that GitLab officially supports Slack integration.
But according to related GitLab documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack.html#triggers-for-slack-notifications)., the Slack integration seems to be designed to work only for particular project, providing all notification related to that project across all users.

I want to achieve something different. I want to get only my personal notifications, but across all projects I participate in (e.g. changes made for tickets assigned to me,  review results, results of pipelines triggered by my etc.).

Is there any way how to do it using just the standard GitLab's Slack integration or standard GitLab configuration? I'm using GitLab Enterprise.

What I have tried already:

- going through GitLab documentation
- Google search for this problem (including stack overflow)
- reading a few tutorials on GitLab ≤≥ Slack connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not directly supported but you can use [Slack Email app](https://slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email?tab=more_info) to forward all the GitLab email notifications to a slack channel:

1. Add the "Slack Email app" to your workspace
2. Create an email address and select the channel used to receive the notifications e.g. Slackbot
3. Go to your GitLab's profile settings page and in the "Email" section, add the new email address
4. Go to the "Notifications" section of your GitLab's profile and use the new email address as "Notification email"

Comment: That looks like a usable solution, thanks! Instead of changing the email address in GitLab directly, you can also set a custom filter with forward rule inside your current email account to achieve finer-grained filtering of the Slack input.

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported.

And note that the [Slack notifications integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack.html) is now deprecated for SaaS customers and will eventually [be removed](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8673).

[GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#notifications-now-available-in-the-gitlab-for-slack-app) (February 2023) only proposes settings per project:

> ### Notifications now available in the GitLab for Slack app
>
> The GitLab for Slack app is the new home for managing notifications from GitLab to your Slack workspace.
>
> Not only can you use existing app features such as [slash commands](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack_slash_commands.html), but you can now also specify which Slack channels you want to notify based on merge request changes, push events, issue changes, and many other GitLab events.

To keep your teams in sync with what’s happening in GitLab, get the [GitLab for Slack app](https://gitlab.slack.com/apps/A676ADMV5-gitlab) today!

> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_9/slack_notifications_jan_31-optimized.png -- Notifications now available in the GitLab for Slack app]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/gitlab_slack_application.html#slack-notifications) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8670).

Although, as noted by [Laurence Gonsalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90848/laurence-gonsalves) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75097176/sending-personal-notifications-from-gitlab-to-slack/75544695?noredirect=1#comment136972654_75544695):

> The Slack notifications deprecation is actually [delayed partly because it doesn't support setting it up at the group level](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/391526#note_1703173628). Sounds like it won't be truly deprecated until possibly as late as 18.0.

---

And [GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#trigger-slack-notifications-for-group-mentions) (September 2023) adds:

> ### Trigger Slack notifications for group mentions
>
> GitLab can send messages to Slack workspace channels for certain GitLab events. With this release, you can now trigger [Slack notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/gitlab_slack_application.html#notification-events) for group mentions in public and private contexts in:
>
> - Issue and merge request descriptions
> - Comments on issues, merge requests, and commits
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/gitlab_slack_application.html#trigger-notifications-for-group-mentions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/417751).

Comment: The Slack notifications deprecation is actually [delayed partly because it doesn't support setting it up at the group level](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/391526#note_1703173628). Sounds like it won't be truly deprecated until possibly as late as 18.0.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution besides the mentioned one with emails is the following, but it requires an additional services with Slack bot integration

- Enable [Gitlab Webhooks with "Job events"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#job-events)
- Write your bot to handle the event

  - bot is going to use [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/reference/functions/send_message) [authorized as a bot](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types)
- Deploy your bot with an exposed publicly a URL for webhooks
- Setup webhook URL in GitLab settings